# weird behaviour when adding a JLabel in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I'm running into a weird thingy here. I'm trying to add a JLabel inside a JTable cell. Label icon may change based on some criteria. I created a dummy project following specs from here: http://javanepal.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/adding-jlabel-in-jtable/

And it works fine. I changed the TableModel to extend from AbstractTableModel instead of DefaultTableModel and when adding a row now I get this if I inspect the Object []:

```
[javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,
flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,
disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,
iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=Row  1,Col1,verticalAlignment=CENTER,
verticalTextPosition=CENTER], whatever....]
```

The code is this, for the TableModel:

```
public class MyModel extends javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel {

    Object[][] row = {{new JLabel("Row 1 Col 1"), "Row 1 Col 2", "Row 1 Col3"},
        {new JLabel("Row 2 Col 1"), "Row 2 Col 2", "Row 2 Col3"},
        {new JLabel("Row 3 Col 1"), "Row 3 Col 2", "Row 3 Col3"},
        {new JLabel("Row 4 Col 1"), "Row 4 Col 2", "Row 4 Col3"}};
    Object[] col = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"};
    protected Vector<Object> data;

    public void addRow(Object o[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            if (o[i] == null) {
                o[i] = new String();
            }
        }
        data.addElement(o);
        fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);
    }

    public MyModel() {
        super();
        data = new Vector<Object>();
        //Adding rows
        for (Object[] r : row) {
            addRow(r);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        } else {
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the testing class:

```
public class MyTableTest extends JFrame {

    public MyTableTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        showGUI();
    }

    public void showGUI() {
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new MyModel());//invoking our custom model
        //loadMessages(table);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(JLabel.class, new Renderer());// for the rendering of cell
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(jp);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTableTest t = new MyTableTest("Table Custom");
    }
}
```

I'm really confused why this happens, the message is not very clarifying regarding the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not post the message, nor what the problem is. But just looking at your code I can already remark a number of issues

1. Why bother storing `JLabel` instances in your `TableModel`. If you want to render the contents of your `TableModel` by using `JLabel` instances, you can do this in the renderer
2. Your `TableModel` implementation returns 0 for both the model and row count (see your `getColumnCount()` and `getRowCount()` methods)
3. Your `getValueAt` always returns `null`, leading to a `NullPointerException` in your `getColumnClass` method since you use `getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass()`
4. Please call the contents of your main method on the EDT

Solve these first and see what happens

Comment: hehehe put both answers together and right now will be there valuable answer, +1

Comment: @mKorbel Indeed. It seems we both missed some points (or left it for the other to share the upvotes). +1 for your answer

Comment: @Robin Well the code is a mix of the example and the table I'm actually using and did it before going to bed, was really tired and didn't bother about unimplemented methods. The first point is absolutely right and lead me to the solution. I'm just checking the column index in the Renderer and return a JLabel instead of a String. Thanks! +1 and correct answer :)

Comment: @mKorbel Hi, I don't really get your first 2 points. And the 3rd, what is the problem of using Object[][] in an AbstractTableModel, specification says nothing wrong about that...http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data, please correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway thanks for you time and help :), really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

1) you can't put `JLabel` to the Cell, Cell by default returns `JComponent/JLabel`

2) you can't put `Icon` to `JLabel`, put `Icon` to `JTable` directly

3) your `AbstractTableModel` has mistake ýou declare for `Object[][]/Object[]` and `Model` is based on `Vector`, by changing `Object[][]` to `Vector<Vector<Object>>` / `Object[]` to `Vector<String>` you can remove this issue

4) don't use `AbstractTableModel`, no reason if you can't restrict or override methods from `DefaultTableModel`

Answer (score 0):

If use JXTreeTable, i will set column 0 is a label type

```
ArrayNode dataRow = new ArrayNode(new Object[]{new JLabel("text",icon), ...});
// add Root --> Set TreeTableModel

.......

jxTreeTable.setTreeCellRenderer(new TreeCellRenderer() {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        AbstractMutableTreeTableNode data = (AbstractMutableTreeTableNode) value;
        if (data.isLeaf()) {// Is Leaf as Label 
            return (JLabel) data.getValueAt(0); // Value 0 is a label
        } else if(data.getValueAt(0)!=null){ // Is Root
            return new JLabel(data.getValueAt(0).toString());
        }else{ // IsRoot, but is Cell Null Value
            return new JLabel("");
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Missing a `}` bracket. Alo, would You care to comment, how is it **actually** related to the question?